# Is it okay to duplicate/persist the same information in two different domains?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have two domains in my application that share the same client concept. One of the domain is the "Directory Component", which is responsible to have all the details related to a client (i.e.: country, phone number, etc.). The other domain is the "Offers Component", which is responsible to have all the details related to offer modeling in the system.

The client exists in both domain, and the country was originally used only in the "Directory Component". New requirements imply the usage of the client's country in the "Offers Component".

During our CRUD process, we have a business logic that orchestrates the creation of a client in all the proper components (in this case Directory and Offers).

We faced two options:

1. During the CRUD process, push the country in the "Offers Component" and persist it in it's own database. This has the drawback of having to synchronize the data in multiple components when updating the country of the client (yes it can happens)
2. Continue to persist the country in the "Directory Component" only, and rely on a service on the top of the domains to gather the country of the client and pass it in the "Offers Component" when required during some of the business case.

We decided to go with option 1, but since I started to read Eric Evans book on DDD (I am still a newbie on this subject), I am questioning the decision we made.

Any one with opinions on that?

Note: removing the service that orchestrates the CRUD creation in multiple component is not an option because of the way the application is designed.

Comment: What did you read in Evans that made you question that decision? Option #1 makes your system a bit more tolerant to partitions (unless you are using distributed transactions), while option #2 is consistent. We cannot tell you which choice is right without knowing more.

Comment: I did not read that option 1 is wrong, but from I read so for (did not finished), it does not seem to have some orientation for this kind of problem. I am sure this is a typical problematic that have a ideal solution. 

The point that I question in the Option #1 is that each time a new domain requires a certain value to do it's job, we need to modify the create/update process, and also implement some migration script that sync the data between domains if the system is already in production. It is quite a pain.

Comment: It's not a pain with a messaging infrastructure in place. You wouldn't synchronize data with migration scripts, but based on events published on an event bus.

Comment: We have a message queuing system used to fire/catch events when "special" things happen. I never though that it would be a nice idea to use it for crud operations.

And by the way, when I said migration script, it was in the case where one day, an existing domain begins to need some existing value from other domain. So when the feature that triggers this requirement goes live, we use migration script to bring the data in that component. Are you saying that in this kind of scenarios you use events/message queuing to accomplish this?!!

Comment: Assuming we use message queuing events to synchronize CRUD operations, how do we choose the "master" component, the one that will trigger the events? Arbitrary choice?

Comment: Well I haven't done it myself, but I think it's pretty common. For instance, with CQRS, if your read model has integrity issues you can simply drop everything and reprocess all the events from the beginning of time to re-create it.

Comment: `"how do we choose the "master" component..."` I'm not sure that I understand the question. The event would originate from the bounded context that fulfilled a command.

Comment: We have a system that has different WCF endpoints. We called this layer the "Facade". Under this layer are all the domains and under this business logic layer, we have the repositories for data persistence. Basically, the Facade's role is to orchestrate all calls (like workflows) between the domains. For exemple, the Facade expose a "CreateClient" method, and the Facade orchestratse the crud operation in all the different domains that are each responsible for data persistence.

Comment: Since each domains have their own responsibility and their own "vision" of the global application, the Facade also orchestrate the different "Read" operations on each domain to aggregate different informations to return to the WCF caller complexes objects that are represented by the data of multiple components. So this is why I assumed that one component should triggers the update event when a properties on an entity (existing in multiple component like the country in my example) is updated.

Comment: Well, from what I can see, the `CreateClient` operation shall belong to a specific bounded context. The context which then initially fulfill this operation will publish events on a bus and other bounded contexts will feed on those events to populate their own data store. Do you have an example of which contexts are involved in the creation process of a client?

Comment: I am sorry I am not fully at ease yet with the domain driven nomenclature (bonded contexts)..

Comment: The CreateClient creates a billable client in the system. It creates it in different domains, which are all separated dlls. One is for everything related to the billing process (Billing Component), an other one is for the parent/childs hierarchy (Directory Component), an other one is for everything the client consumes (Offer Component), an other one is for the infrastructure provisioning (Provisioning Component). So I think those are all contexts. And it's in those components (domains/dll/database) that the Facade orchestrate the creation of the entity.

Comment: Ok, well as far as I can tell, you will have to pick one of your contexts which will be responsible for the creation of a client. You know your contexts better than I, but we can probably tell it doesn't belong in the billing component for instance. Then other contexts will react to a ClientCreated event.

Answer (score 2):

Using DDD you should aim to keep each Bounded Context separate. This might result in modelling similarly named classes with possibly some common properties in both BCs.  Any synchronisation/communication between the systems and creation of similar entities could be kept up to date using a mechanism at application level.  This could be web services or something like an ESB (Enterprise Service Bus).  Each system would be complete and own its own persistence data source (database), if required.  Each system at application level shouldn't meddle in the another system's database.  Allowing direct database manipulation from another BC or external system, bypasses any business logic that may be in place.

The examples given in the two main DDD books suggest that the needs in each separate Bounded Context for some concept like a Client, would be different and require the Client to be modelled differently in each BC and allowed to evolve separately.